# Multiple games in same box using same components. What was it?

Tags: identify-this-game

Several years ago I was at a friends house and he had this particular item.

It was a box full of simple components, a board, and rules for multiple games. The idea behind it was the components were given to several designers (4 or 5 I think), and they each created a game using the components in the box. I don't remember the name of it, or the names of any of the game designers.

Things I remember about the games:

- Some of the components were wooden pegs. The pegs were of various heights, and there were the same set of pegs for multiple colours (4 or 5?)
- One of the games was about (or a major component of it was) holding elections
- One of the games (I think) was about building stonehenge
- One of the games awarded the title "Mighty Beard" to the winner. I believe in this game each player was a druid
- The passage of Day and Night was relevant to some games. Things that were good at night were bad during the day, and vis versa.
- I think the board had circles of various sizes on it, with smaller circles inside the larger circles

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds like [Stonehenge: an anthology board game](http://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/20436/stonehenge):

> Stonehenge is an anthology board game, a new concept where five award-winning game designers, all using the same gaming components, create five very different games in one box. The ancient ruin of Stonehenge will never be the same. The five games are:
>
> - a magic game by Richard Garfield (Magic: The Gathering, RoboRally, The Great Dalmuti)
> - a political game by Bruno Faidutti (Mystery of the Abbey, Citadels, Knightmare Chess)
> - a battle game by Richard Borg (Battle Cry, Liar's Dice, Memoir '44)
> - an auction game by James Ernest (Kill Dr. Lucky, Diceland, Pirates of the Spanish Main)
> - a science-fiction game by Mike Selinker (Risk Godstorm, Pirates, Axis & Allies Revised)

Comment: Yep that is it. Looks like I had a few of the details wrong